# Как установить arm-none-eabi-gcc 4.9.3?

Tags: linux, arm

ОС - linux. При установке командой `sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-embedded` устанавливается версия 7.3.0, которая не подходит. Скачал с сайта архив тулчейна версии 4.9.3 а что делать дальше?

Comment: В архиве с исходниками нет инструкции по установке?

Comment: *а что делать дальше?* — читать **инструкцию**. на сайте, либо в самом архиве. по-другому — увы, никак.

Answer (score 1):

Если совсем ничего непонятно, то делайте так:

1. Разтарьте архив кросс-компиллера в любое место.
2. Переложите его бинарники куда-то, куда считаете нужным. Например у меня они лежат в каталоге */usr/bin*/ Под словом "бинарники" я понимаю файлы вида "arm-linux-gnueabihf-*". Среди них будет нечто вроде:

   ```
   arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar
   arm-linux-gnueabihf-as
   ...
   arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-5
   arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-5
   ```

   Не обязательно их ложить в /usr/bin/, можно в отдельный каталог, но тогда этот каталог нужно добавить в PATH. Туда же нужно положить и символические  ссылки, если понадобятся.
3. Создайте каталог проекта, в котором будет кросс-компилировать приложение.
4. В этом каталоге создайте  tool-chain для cMake приблизительно такого вида:

   ```
   $ cat ARM-toolchain 

   SET( CMAKE_C_COMPILER  linux-gnueabihf-gcc )
   SET( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER linux-gnueabihf-g++ )
   SET( CMAKE_STRIP arm-cortexa9_neon-linux-gnueabihf-strip )
   SET( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MinSizeRel )
   SET( CROSS true )
   add_definitions( -DCROSS )
   ```

   Обратите внимание, что здесь я уже использую символические ссылки, что бы не менять
   *toolchain* при смене версии кросс-компиляторов. Вместо *arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-5* я указал линк *linux-gnueabihf-gcc* которая указывает на версию компилятора по умолчанию.
5. В каталоге проекта создайте *CMakeLists.txt* Что это такое, я здесь уж объяснять не буду.
6. Создайте папку ARM_build и перейдите в эту папку.
7. Выполните команду:

   ```
   $ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../ARM-toolchain ..
   ```

   *cmake* возьмёт Вашу toolchain и создаст *Makefile*, в котором пропишет копиляторы для кросс-компиляции.
8. Запускаем сборку

   ```
   $ make
   ```